# Serializing a POJO with only fields that are modified?

Tags: java, serialization, pojo

I have a bunch of POJOs I want to serialize / deserialize to JSON.

However, I'm selectively reading only *some* of the fields from cassandra.

So when I serialize the object to JSON, I only want those objects that were read from the database.

So all setters need to code to track that the member has been mutated/defined.

That way when I go to serialize, only the modified fields are included.

I have dozens of fields in this schema so I'd prefer to not have to write the setters directly.

Are there any POJO frameworks that do this for me?

there's no 'undefined' in Java so the default is 'null' unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is your friend in this case.

If I'm understanding you correctly and the "unmodified" fields will be null at the time of serialization, and assuming you're using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations), just add the following annotation to the top of your class:

```
 @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) //alternatively @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)  
 class Foo {
```

This will exclude any null (or, alternatively, empty) values from the serialized object.

If I'm not understanding you correctly and "unmodified" fields will *not* be null or empty, it'll be a little trickier, but not much. Let me know and I'll update with some tips.

(PS if you check out that link, you'll see that Jackson has a lot of other handy annotations)

Comment: Great feedback.  I literally just came up with the same solution on my own so I guess great minds think alike!  My changes is to use Integers not ints.. this way when I call something like getValue() my code fails since the value was not sent. I don't like having to throw an NPE but this is will work for right now.

Comment: @burtonator Well I guess they do then:) That happens to me quite often when I post questions here. PS - since you're new here: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it. I noticed you've never done that before, and you should - it lets future users know this solution worked, and it gives you a couple of reputation points!

Comment: Thanks.. done.  The 'accept' UI isn't super clear.  I might go back and do that to my previous posts.